# How to get device charging type in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to get the type of charging method used to charge the device in my application (e.g. if device is getting charged using USB or wireless charger)

I am aware that we can know whether the device is being charged, but how can we get the method of charging?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get iPhone charger's information in iOS 10+ using private API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457127/is-there-a-way-to-get-iphone-chargers-information-in-ios-10-using-private-api)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this library on GitHub,
https://github.com/eldade/EEIOKitListener.

It provides a lot of information related to charging.

Comment: I have already checked into this library. It is using IOKit which is private API and also it doesn't provide charging status for iOS 12